# MySQL query performance with reference tables

Tags: mysql, query-performance

For the following 2 tables structures, assuming the data volume is really high:

```
cars table
Id | brand name | make year | purchase year | owner name
```

Is there any query performance benefit with structuring it this way and joining the 2 tables instead?

```
cars table
Id | brand_id | make year | purchase year | owner name

brands table
Id | name
```

Also, if all 4 columns fall in my where clause, does it make sense indexing any?

Comment: A new table has a data integrity benefit anyway. Performance you will have to measure. It might or might not depending on your queries.  Same for indexing.  Depends on what you are doing.  Maybe 4 indexes, maybe one.

Comment: A composite index on all 4 columns (and in that order), might be useful, but beware that a query that didn't use the first columns of the index couldn't then make use of the subsequent columns of the index.

Comment: @LoztlnSpace so if i store brand name as string in cars table, or store it as int instead and join with a brands table, doesnt really affect performance?

Comment: @Strawberry indexing all columns isnt like no indexing at all? can't go with composite, coz not necessarily all 4 columns will fall in my where clause

Comment: All 5 columns would be equivalent to no index. You just have to work out which composite index will work for the majority of your more demanding queries. You can work this out scientifically, but I tend to adopt a more 'suck-it-and-see' approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would at least have `INDEX(owner_name)` since that is very selective.  Having `INDEX(owner_name, model_year)` won't help enough to matter *for this type of data*.  There are other cases where I would recommend a 4-column composite index.

"data volume is really high".  If you are saying there are 100K rows, then it does not matter much.  If you are saying a billion rows, then we need to get into a lot more details.

"data volume is really high".  10 queries/second -- Yawn.  1000/second -- more details, please.

2 tables vs 1.

- Data integrity - someone could mess up the data either way
- Speed -- a 1-byte `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (range 0..255) is smaller than an average of about 7 bytes for `VARCHAR(55) for`brand`.  But it is hardly enough smaller to matter on space or speed.  (And if you goof and make`brand_id`a`BIGINT`, which is 8 bytes; well, oops!)

Indexing all columns is different than having no indexes.  But "indexing all" is ambiguous:

- `INDEX(user), INDEX(brand), INDEX(year), ...` is likely to make it efficient to search or sort by any of those columns.
- `INDEX(user, brand, year), ...` makes it especially efficient to search by all those columns (with `=`), or certain `ORDER BYs`.
- No index implies scanning the entire table for *any* `SELECT`.

Another interpretation of what you said (plus a little reading between the lines):  Might you be searching by any combination of columns?  Perhaps non-`=` things like `year >= 2016`?  Or `make IN ('Toyota', 'Nissan')`?

Study http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

**An argument for 1 table**

If you need to do

```
WHERE brand = 'Toyota'
  AND year  = 2017
```

Then `INDEX(brand, year)` (in either order) is possible and beneficial.

But...  If those two columns are in different tables (as with your 2-table example), then you *cannot* have such an index, and performance will suffer.

Comment: Thanks Rick James, nicely said. Just to put it again, if I have say all in one table, there will be "brand_name" which is string. If 2 tables, then "brand_id" + a join. Performance wise, 2 tables vs 1 in this case? my records are above 3million and growing.

Comment: 1 table.  See my addenda.

Comment: just checked that. besides the index value, is searching in a tiny brands table by string and linking to the huge table with id (int) is going to give me any performance benefit you think?

Comment: @aiiwa - It won't make a lot of difference.  When you next find a performance problem, it will probably be in some other area.